# buttons not copying with sheet excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have some macros that copy my sheet in excel,and delete certain data. Unfortunately the buttons to which the macros are assigned do not copy over when the macros are run.

```
Sub CandD()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim sh As Shape, strtSh As Worksheet
    Set strtSh = ActiveSheet
    Sheets("BM Condition").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "BM Condition" & Sheets.Count - 1
    Range("E14:E33,I14:I33,M14:M33").ClearContents
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        sh.Delete
    Next sh
    strtSh.Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

This is the macro I am using. I have very limited VBA experience and am not finding google very helpful. Could someone recommend a fix for my buttons not copying over?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that when manually copying the buttons remain. I am not sure why this is.

Comment: Get rid of the `sh.Delete` (and the loop around)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As FunThomas mentioned, I've tried and tested the following without any errors:

```
Sub CanD()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim sh As Shape, strtSh As Worksheet
    Set strtSh = ActiveSheet

    Sheets("BM Condition").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "BM Condition" & Sheets.Count - 1

    Range("E14:E33,I14:I33,M14:M33").ClearContents

    strtSh.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```